How to mimic amsart's spacing of \begin{equation} environment in a standard report?
I am writing my thesis using the \documentclass[...]{report} class, and I would like the \begin{equation} environment to have the same vertical spacing as in \documentclass[...]{amsart} (which uses less space). I have consulted the amsart documentation but was unable to solve the problem.
The code I used is the following:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
%\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, mathtools}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    \label{thm:L1-CalphaW12}
    Let $B_1$ denote the unit ball of $\R^n$. 
    Assume that $u\in C^2(B_1)$ is a stable 
    solution of
    $$
    -\Delta u=f(u) \quad \text{in }B_1,
    $$
    with  $f:\R \to\R$ locally Lipschitz and nonnegative.
    
    Then
    \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:W12g L1 int}
        \|\nabla u\|_{L^{2+\gamma}({B}_{1/2})} \le C\|u\|_{L^1(B_1)},
    \end{equation}
    where $\gamma>0$ and $C$  are dimensional constants.
    In addition, if $n \leq 9$ then
    \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:Ca L1 int}
        \|u\| _{C^\alpha(\overline{B}_{1/2})}\leq C\|u\|_{L^1(B_1)},
    \end{equation}
    where $\alpha>0$ and $C$  are dimensional constants.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}

Below are two outputs for reference:

When the first line is commented (i.e. using amsart). This is the desired spacing.


When the second line is commented (i.e. using report). This is how it currently looks.



What can I do to achieve the desired vertical spacing in the report class?
Thank you very much.
P.S.: I prefer not to change report to amsart since I am writing a thesis, and the latter is intended for articles.
P.S.: The theorem is from this paper.

you could use amsproc (or amsbook) for a ams flavoured class closer to report

@DavidCarlisle I edited the question, hopefully it is clearer now. Thanks.

thanks.........

The AMS classes do \@adjustvertspacing when (some) size changing commands are issued.
We can emulate it.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\adjustvertspacing}{%
  \bigskipamount.7\baselineskip plus.7\baselineskip
  \medskipamount\bigskipamount \divide\medskipamount 2
  \smallskipamount\medskipamount \divide\smallskipamount 2
  \abovedisplayskip\medskipamount
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
  \abovedisplayshortskip\abovedisplayskip
  \advance\abovedisplayshortskip-1\abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip\abovedisplayshortskip
  \advance\belowdisplayshortskip 1\smallskipamount
  \jot\baselineskip \divide\jot 4 \relax
}

\AddToHook{cmd/normalsize/after}{\adjustvertspacing}
\AddToHook{cmd/small/after}{\adjustvertspacing}
\AddToHook{cmd/footnotesize/after}{\adjustvertspacing}
\AddToHook{cmd/large/after}{\adjustvertspacing}
\AddToHook{cmd/Large/after}{\adjustvertspacing}
\AtBeginDocument{\adjustvertspacing}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[18][1-4]
\[
a+b=c
\]
\lipsum[19][1-3]

Short line
\[
a+b=c
\]
\lipsum[20][1-4]

\bigskip

The parameters' values:

\the\abovedisplayskip

\the\abovedisplayshortskip

\the\belowdisplayskip

\the\belowdisplayshortskip

\end{document}

You can check that amsbook uses the same values.


Interesting. I've never heard about \jot. Thanks.
